# Activity vs. View. vs. SurfaceView and interaction

Tags: android, view, android-activity, surfaceview, ontouchlistener

I am trying to make a fairly simple Android game. I am making a custom view: I am not using any buttons, rather, I am painting pixels on screen that represent buttons. The idea is that I have 3 screens:

- A Main screen
- A Play screen
- An Instructions screen

The main menu has two "locations" to click on: one that says Play (via painted pixels) and another that says Instructions.

I am confused as to how these should be implemented. Right now, I have a Main activity that sets the content view to the Main screen (extends View) but I am confused as to how to go from that Main screen (View) to the Play or Instructions screen. I have read up on View, Activities and SurfaceView but without any luck in understanding.

Does anyone have any examples (with proper programming practices) to make a view interactive and show another View (potentially Activity that creates a View?) Thanks!

Comment: usually I am not trying to reinvent the wheel anymore: I would search any free game engine with a hello word tutorial and is done what you need based on a TESTED framework

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out ? I had similar confusion today , but think I have figured it out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need are some basic Android game development tutorials. To get started, [this short tutorial](http://mobile-development.org/index.php/android/introduction-to-android-game-development-part-1) is well-arranged and covers a Main-Screen, which leads to a Game-Screen. It will definitely help you out to get started. I personally also like video-tutorials, that's why I would recommend [this series of tutorials](http://www.edu4java.com/androidgame.html) which is suitable for beginners, too. Finally [this page](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/android-game-development-tutorials.html) shows a lot of Android gaming tutorials. That are my personal favorits as it comes to gaming tutorials for beginners, but you will find a lot of stuff out there in the web. Have fun!

Comment: These tutorials were great, thank you! Sorry it took so long to approve; newbie to this site... didn't quite understand the etiquette at first!